# Self-adjointness under relatively bounded perturbation

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a densely defined linear operator on a Banach space $X$. Another operator $A$ satisfying $\mathcal{D}(T) \subset \mathcal{D}(A)$ is called a relatively bounded perturbation of $T$ if $$\Vert Au\Vert \leq a\Vert Tu\Vert + b\Vert u\Vert, u \in \mathcal{D}(T), a, b \geq 0$$
I am asking, if $T$ is known to be self-adjoint and $A$ is symmetric, then is $A + T$ also self-adjoint?  I would really be happy with a reference where I can read the theory up.

Note: Edited after gerw's reply.

Answer (score 2):

The Kato-Rellich Theorem gives an answer to this question. It is found in most text books on functional analysis. For example in the book Introduction to Spectral Theory by P. D. Hislop, I. M. Sigal in chapter 13.